# Returning a struct in Golang

Tags: oop, go, struct

I'm just starting with Golang and I am very confused about interacting with other packages and using structs. Right now I am simply trying to return the a struct generated by a method in the gopsutil library. Specifically the return of the following function: [enter link description here](https://godoc.org/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/cpu#Times)

My code for this is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/cpu"

)

func main() {

    cpu_times = getCpuTime()
    fmt.Println(cpu_times)

}

func getCpuTime() TimesStat {
    ct, _ := cpu.Times(false)

    return ct
}
```

This returns `TimesStat` as undefined. I tried returning a few different syntactical variations, however the only return value I have found that compiles is `interface{}`, which gets me the struct inside of brackets (eg `[{values...}]`) and that led to some other problems. I can't seem to find any examples of what I am trying to do. Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to include the package name before the type, like so:

```
func getCpuTime() []cpu.TimesStat { // with package name before type
    ct, _ := cpu.Times(false)

    return ct
}
```

since that is a slice of `cpu.TimesStat`, you probably want to add an index in the calling function or change the function to just return a single `cpu.TimesStat`. (thanks to @algrebre)

Comment: [cpu#Times](https://godoc.org/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/cpu#Times) returns `([]TimesStat, error)` so `getCpuTime()` should return `[]cpu.TimeStat`. I can't make such a small edit since its a two character insertion.

Comment: changed with comment, Thanks @algrebe!